# Are there performance differences in queries with UNIQUE NON NULL indexes and Primary keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I want to search a DB with either the PK or a unique non null field that is indexed. Are there any performance differences between those? I am using Postgres as my DB. But a general DB-independent answer would be good too.

Comment: You can't get a db-independent answer since different products handle things in slightly different ways.

Comment: Fun fact: the ANSI SQL specification does not mention indexes. They are a vendor extension to the SQL language in all implementations.

Comment: It would depend on the types of indexes. In PostgreSQL PKs are typically implemented with b-tree indexes and if the other column is using the same type of indexes, then there shouldn't be any difference. Now, if the other index is of a different type, then there will definitively be differences.

Comment: A strange question... Do you have the same that in 2 different columns?

Comment: **Test it**. Build a table defining with several columns. Then populate it with 100K rows or so. The define a column as the PK. Now several queries and capture run time for each. Now drop the PK and define the same column(s) as Unique Not Null and build an corresponding index, then *rerun the same queries* (make sure prior run are not still buffered). Compare the run times. Also look at the difference in the explain plains for each. Is there any? This should work within any RDBMS but not across them.

Answer (score 1):

In **postgreSQL**, [all indexes are *secondary* or *unclustered* indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html). That means the the index points to the *heap*, the data structure holding the actual column data. So, a primary key's index doesn't have any structural advantage over a UNIQUE index: SELECTs using the index for filtering must then bounce over to the heap for the data.

In fact, it might be the other way around, because postgreSQL indexes can have INCLUDES clauses.

For example consider a table with `uniqueid`, `a`, `b`, and `c` columns. If your workload is heavy with `SELECT b FROM tbl WHERE uniqueid = something` queries, you can declare this *covering index*.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniq ON tbl(uniqueid) INCLUDE (b);
```

Your whole query can then be satisfied from the index. That saves the extra trip to the heap, and so saves IO and CPU time.

**MySQL** and **SQL Server**, on the other hand, use *clustered indexes* for their primary keys.  That is, the table's data is stored *in the primary key's index*. So, the PK is, automatically, basically an index created like this.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pk ON tbl(uniqueid) INCLUDE (a, b, c);
```

In those databases the PK's index does have an advantage over a separate UNIQUE index, which necessarily is a secondary or unclustered index. (Note: MySQL's indexes don't have `INCLUDE()` clauses.)